# EndReceive in Async Socket without strings

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcplistener, asyncsocket

I'm following this example about the creation of an async tcp listener in C#.
[MSDN Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example)

I see that all data is encoded as string to check for message completeness. More precisely, every message sent is already a string, which we append the 'EOF' char to for string termination.

The server side part i'm talking about is in this snippet:

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
    String content = String.Empty;  

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
    // from the asynchronous state object.  
    StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;  
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;  

    // Read data from the client socket.   
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);  

    if (bytesRead > 0) {  
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(  
            state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));  

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read   
        // more data.  
        content = state.sb.ToString();  
        if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {  
            // All the data has been read from the   
            // client. Display it on the console.  
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",  
                content.Length, content );  
            // Echo the data back to the client.  
            Send(handler, content);  
        } else {  
            // Not all data received. Get more.  
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,  
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Is there a way, as i usually do with TcpListener/TcpClient classes, to check if received bytes are available on the socket?

I mean something like this:

```
    private void HandleClientConnection(TcpClient client)
    {
        NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        while (true)
        {
            int read = clientStream.ReadByte();

            if (read != -1)
            {
                memoryStream.WriteByte((byte)read);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm aware that i probably misunderstood this example, or at least the Begin/End part and the "legacy" async pattern. But this is my goal, do you know some way to get it working without involving strings?

Answer (score 1):

You said : "Is there a way to check if received bytes are available on the socket?"

In general 'EndReceive' will block the thread until data is available. So you don't need to do anything because 'EndReceive' is doing all the job for you.

'bytesRead' is an int that shows you how much data you have received.

a quote from docs.microsoft

> The EndReceive method will block until data is available.[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.endreceive?view=netframework-4.8)

But if you are using a SYNC socket (which you are not) then it's another topic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So all the stringbuilder stuff it's going on in this example is just related to the example domain (full string send/receive), i think. Do you agree on that?